# Angular app not working on iphone and some devices and has no error

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, google-tag-manager, angular-service-worker

I deployed my angular app last week and it was working fine in all devices, i added pwa and google tag and noticed some users cannot load app and saw google tag error on console, i removed it and now all my pc browsers can load it correctly but cannot load it on my iphone (i cleared cache and also tried to use different isp) also users cannot load app without VPN
the weird thing is there is no error on console, i tried to push without `--prod` flag and even though loads as development mode dosent show any errors!

dependencies and asset groups in `ngsw.config.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ],
        "urls": [
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/**",
          "https://fonts.gstatic.com/**",
          "https://kit.fontawesome.com/*",
          "https://www.googletagmanager.com/**"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
```

`package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~11.2.8",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^11.1.1",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^11.1.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^11.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^11.1.1",
    "angular-datatables": "^12.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.24",
    "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.20",
    "datatables.net-buttons": "^1.7.0",
    "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "^1.7.0",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.24",
    "datatables.net-searchbuilder-dt": "^1.0.1",
    "html2canvas": "^1.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jszip": "^3.6.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "swiper": "^6.6.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.8",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^11.1.1",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
    "@types/datatables.net-buttons": "^1.4.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Are the users connected to a corporate network? There may be blocking there. That may explain why they work with the VPN turned on. (A guess)

Comment: i noticed my pc using 8.8.8.8 dns, so once i remove this dns, i also cannot access the app on my pc same as iphone. also it is not angular anymore because i removed the app from host and use simple index.html but still cannot access without 8.8.8.8 or vpn. Im using aws server and godday for domain if it help to find the reason

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help, but I had the same problem where my login feature wouldn't work on some devices.

What had happened was, I was using `string.prototype.replaceAll()` but it seems that `string.prototype.replaceAll()` is not available on the browser version on my iPhone. So I changed `.replaceAll()` with `.replace()` and it worked. So for you, I'm guessing you're using a method that's not supported by the browser version on your iPhone.